# Stencil component which uses store loses context if multiple tests are run

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, stenciljs

stencil store: 2.0.9

stencil core: 4.0.2

#### Current Behavior

I have implemented a basic store in a stencil test project. Whenever I try to set store values en reset them in my test; the test loses the context and cannot find the component anymore. If I run a single test instead of both, it does not have any issue.

**my-component.tsx**

```
import { Component, State, h } from '@stencil/core';
import { store, onStoreChange } from '../../store/store';

@Component({
  tag: 'my-component',
  styleUrl: 'my-component.css',
  shadow: true,
})
export class MyComponent {
  @State() test = true;

  setTestState() {
    this.test = !this.test;
  }

  componentWillLoad() {
    onStoreChange('isActive', this.setTestState.bind(this));
  }

  render() {
    return <div>Hello, World! I'm</div>;
  }
}
```

**my-component.spec.ts**

```
import { newSpecPage } from '@stencil/core/testing';
import { MyComponent } from './my-component';
import { store } from '../../store/store';

describe('my-component', () => {
   afterEach(() => {
    store.dispose();
  });

  it('renders', async () => {
    const { root } = await newSpecPage({
      components: [MyComponent],
      html: '<my-component></my-component>',
    });

    store.state.isActive = false;

    expect(root).toEqualHtml(`
      <my-component>
        <mock:shadow-root>
          <div>
            Hello, World! I'm
          </div>
        </mock:shadow-root>
      </my-component>
    `);
  });
  
  it('renders', async () => {
    const { root } = await newSpecPage({
      components: [MyComponent],
      html: '<my-component></my-component>',
    });

    store.state.isActive = false;

    expect(root).toEqualHtml(`
      <my-component>
        <mock:shadow-root>
          <div>
            Hello, World! I'm
          </div>
        </mock:shadow-root>
      </my-component>
    `);
  });
});
```

**store.ts**

```
import { createStore } from '@stencil/store';

export interface StoreState {
  isActive: boolean;
}

const store = createStore<StoreState>({
  isActive: true
});

const onStoreChange = (key: keyof StoreState, cb: (value: string | boolean) => void): void => {
  store.onChange(key, (value: any) => {
    cb(value);
  });
};

export { store, onStoreChange };
```

Current error
 `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$instanceValues$')`

#### Code Reproduction URL

https://github.com/pimmesz/stencil-test

Comment: I did a quick `npm test` in that code, and it all passes

Answer (score 0):

I have reviewed the code you provided and I believe the issue is that you are calling `store.dispose()` in the `afterEach()` block of your test. This is causing the store to be destroyed before the next test is run.

To fix this, you can move the call to `store.dispose()` to the `afterAll()` block. This will ensure that the store is not destroyed until after all of the tests have been run.

Here is the updated code:

```
import { newSpecPage } from '@stencil/core/testing';
import { MyComponent } from './my-component';
import { store } from '../../store/store';

describe('my-component', () => {

  afterAll(() => {
    store.dispose();
  });

  it('renders', async () => {
    const { root } = await newSpecPage({
      components: [MyComponent],
      html: '<my-component></my-component>',
    });

    store.state.isActive = false;

    expect(root).toEqualHtml(`
      <my-component>
        <mock:shadow-root>
          <div>
            Hello, World! I'm
          </div>
        </mock:shadow-root>
      </my-component>
    `);
  });

  it('renders', async () => {
    const { root } = await newSpecPage({
      components: [MyComponent],
      html: '<my-component></my-component>',
    });

    store.state.isActive = false;

    expect(root).toEqualHtml(`
      <my-component>
        <mock:shadow-root>
          <div>
            Hello, World! I'm
          </div>
        </mock:shadow-root>
      </my-component>
    `);
  });
});
```

I hope this helps!